At what point in the Shuttle's design process was the 3g acceleration limit uncovered for the second stage of flight?
I'm watching a new documentary on the Shuttle, and one of the astronauts talks about how during the second stage, they limit the acceleration of the vehicle to 3g, to prevent the wings from shearing off.
This limit surprised me, as I always considered any acceleration within the nominal limiting one of 5-10g for consciousness to be the "target" upper limit, and that other challenges could be engineered around. Additionally, as I understand it the atmosphere is quite thin by the time second stage begins, so the stresses on the vehicle are already below Max-Q.
How was this limit calculated? Was it uncovered early or late in the design process? What implications did it have for the structural design of the Shuttle?

The 3g limit was designed in from the earliest stages of the program.
It was not "uncovered", it was a program level requirement.
The program level requirements for Phase B of the development effort in the Shuttle System Specification dated June 1 1970 included

Both elements shall provide a 'shirt sleeve environment` with trajectory load factors of less than 3 g

("Both elements" refers to the separate booster and orbiter originally planned)
Reference: Document is quoted in Jenkins, "Space Shuttle", 1992 edition, page 73.
Opinion: It wasn't to keep the wings on. It was because the system requirements specifiers wished to make the system as inclusive of the general population as possible.

"Shirt sleeve" is a new analogy to me. Is this in reference to normal office clothing? Thanks for the citation!

@ijustlovemath "Shirt-sleeve environment" is a term used in aircraft design to describe the interior of an aircraft in which no special clothing need be worn." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirt-sleeve_environment Obviously the shuttle didn't meet that goal for launch and landing.

I did a little digging hoping we could point to a publicly-available-on-the-internet source and Space shuttle system program definition. Volume 2: Technical report mentions the 3-g design limit on 6-3 (pg 204) and 9-18 (pg 265) and a few other places, always as "3 g" or "3g". Figs 5-8 and 5-23 explicitly call out places where 3G boost is a major structural design consideration. Fascinating stage of design.

@OrganicMarble I think the environment in the interior of the shuttle would have for that also during ascent and landing. Wern't they even wearing simple work overalls from STS-5 until Challenger? Yeah, an Overall is not really "shirt sleeve" but still :)

@TrySCE2AUX I considered the Launch and Entry helmets a disqualifier for "shirt sleeve" https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/helmet-backshell-launch-entry-shuttle/nasm_A20130280000 but otherwise yeah.

@ErinAnne thanks for that reference. I couldn't find the exact document quoted either.


I think the spaceman was pulling your leg. The acceleration is limited at ~480s by an automated throttle. The limit is for crew comfort, not to prevent the wings falling off
https://www.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/ochmo-tb-024-acceleration.pdf
includes a good bunch of reasons to limit exposure even to 3g. The maximum loads for the wings are seen in the lower atmosphere on re-entry and landing, not ascent- although possibly not in the longitudinal axis.
Here's plot including max-q - the maximum aerodynamic loads. It is at around t=60, not 480 when the 3 g is reached

It seems that early studies for the Shuttle threw up an expected limit of +3g -1g for flight loads, and they used a safety factor of 1.4, rather than the typical 1.5 for civilian aircraft. The intention was that after 100 flights there should still be a safety factor of 1.2.

If so, he was misquoting a story to a documentary, which seems unlikely!

Doesn't pass the sniff test, the 3g limit was hit as they left upper atmosphere - there would be no aerodynamic loads to tear the wing off.

Here is a 30 second clip which inspired the question. I think I'd trust an astronaut's understanding of the vehicle over this answer, but I'm open to discussion on what he might have meant: https://youtube.com/watch?v=w4FCkbPykdQ&t=15m52s

I must confess I am having little success in identifying the design loads for the Shuttle. IF 3g longitudinal was the maximum designed load (a big if), then yes, the wings might have been designed to fall off at 3g*SF, where SF was 1.4. Bear in mind they also had fatigue loads to design to, as lowest SF after 100 flights was 1.25. At least in cars fatigue is the limiting loads for many components.

There was a general target of 3 g for ascent and 2.5g for descent, so yes if the wings were designed to fall off at 1.4*3g then they would have met spec. Apparently high stress low cycle fatigue was not a limiting load case.

@ijustlovemath With all due respect to Mr. Melnick's history as a test pilot, he's not part of the shuttle design team, and his thoughts on why the accelerations are limited in various phases of flight are not necessarily in line with what the engineering team intended. In fact, as an ex-test pilot, he's probably more likely to think in terms of envelope limits as being related to ultimate load rather than to the need to keep the nerds in back from passing out.

Do astronauts not undergo extensive courses on the design and limitations of the vehicle, so they can appropriately make split second decisions/be able to contribute to important procedures? Surely that sort of training would make you close to an expert on the vehicle.

Didn't the structural requirement flow from the operational requirement? I would expect them to match (with adequate margin, of course).

No, they selected a flight envelope and decided to use the same as a commercial aircraft, +3g -1g. They went slightly low on the SF at1.4. 3g was also judged to be the limit for the squishy cargo.

@GregLocock So, you're saying +3g -1g was the operational requirement, and  they derived the structural requirement from that.

That sounds right to me, but the sheer volume of literature on this is overwhelming. There's a lot of it on MIT Open Course Ware, particularly the systems engineering course.

@ijustlovemath, remember 'astronaut' includes several US politicians and a Saudi prince. For Melnick it looks like he was a mission specialist focusing on satellite launch and repair rather than a shuttle pilot, so those teaching him may have told https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children to maximise the learning of 'if this happens do this' and skipping WHY a thing was the way it is. He also flew pre Challanger loss, so may have full on been lied to by NASA on risk related matters.

@GremlinWranger Could be... but also, his training was over 30 years ago, so it's entirely possible he's mixing things up or made assumptions rather than being actively lied to. Could be he recalled that there was a G limit during launch, but mixed up the reason with a different G limit, possibly one related to reentry forces. Or it's possible they never told him the reason, just said "At this point the engines throttle back to limit the G load" and he merely assumed that was a structural limit. 30 years ago, I was in middle school, and I barely remember any of it with any clarity!

@GremlinWranger I can easily understand the "lie to children" aspect. While the 3g limit was indeed for crew and passengers, telling them that it was for the structural integrity of the vehicle might have been easier for macho astronauts (who sometimes act like children) to swallow.
